# unknown host for domain on ec2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, dns

I have an EC2 instance with WHM installed and I'm trying to host a website on it. I can ping the EC2 just fine but attempting to ping the domain gets me "unknown host". As far as I can tell my DNS and vhost info is set up correctly.

Is there some common configuration step I'm missing to get a domain up and running on ec2?

Comment: I think you need a DNS entry in Route 53 so that you can reach your instance WHM. Is your website open to internet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 'A record' for DNS to bind domain to IP address. This can be done in route 53, there are various types of options please find [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-configuring.html) that suits you.

Comment: I appreciate the fast answer. I think I need to go into more detail; The ec2 instance is in a DNS cluster with two other servers, neither of which are ec2 instances but rather servers from a separate hosting company. We use a common set of name servers for all three, or that's the goal at least. How does that change what I need to do?